# How to Create an Array with Same Element repeated multiple times in Arduino?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

```
**array=[symbol,count,symbol,count.....]
for eg: array=[3,2,5,4..]
new_array=[3,3,5,5,5,5...]**

      int array[]={25,6,10,2,4,3,9,5};
       int value1[16]={0};
        Serial.print("\n RLE decoded");
       for(i=0;i<len;i++)
       {
         if(i%2==0)
         {
           value[i] = array[i];
           i=i+1;
           count=array[i];
         }
         for(j=0; j<count;j++)
         {

           Serial.print(value[i]);
           Serial.print('\t');
         }
```

How to Create an Array with Same Element repeated multiple times in Arduino?
This code is working properly and we are able to print repeatedly the symbols but the problem with this code is :: the repeated the values are not getting stored to a new array. we tried with declaring a new array to store the repeated values but it is not working!!

Comment: Please don't repeat yourself, instead describe the problems you have with the code you show and your own thoughts about those problems. Please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You need to independently track position in `value` array, since it will be different from position in input `array`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array is a collection of the same elements, but symbol and count are obviously different things. To group different things together, `struct` was invented in the earliest days of C

```
struct {char symbol;  byte count;} input[] = {
  {'a', 2}, {'X' ,3} ,{'!', 1}  
};

const byte inputcount = sizeof(input)/sizeof(input[0]); // 3 in this test
char expanded[20]; // will get the result 

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   char* resultpos = expanded;
   for (auto& elem:input) { 
      for (byte p = 0; p < elem.count; p++) {
         *resultpos++ = elem.symbol;
      }
   }
   *resultpos = 0; // to make it a printable char array
   Serial.println(expanded); // should give "aaXXX!"
}
void loop() {}
```

If you prefer, you can use the classic type of for loop as well. But this `for each` is really nice, IMO.

Comment: No check for sufficient size of expanded, yet !